# How do i correctly type hint in my own python package

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Im currently creating my first own package in python using twine. In my test folder the autocompletion in pycharm works like a charm. See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCThx.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx9TB.png)

But if uploaded to testpypl and downloaded to a new project its not working anymore [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8pHG.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQhAe.png)

Currently my method looks like this:

```
async def championships(self, game: Game, type: MatchType = MatchType.ALL, offset: int = 0,
                        limit: int = 10) -> Collection[Championship]:
```

Do I need to add some special docstrings for this to work?
I saw other packages with this kind of docstrings:

```
"""
:param summoner_id: summoner ID
:return: list of masteries for the given summoner
:type summoner_id: str
:rtype: List[:class:`~types.ChampionMasteryDto`]
"""
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: Don't link to images. Put the relevant information in the question itself as text.

Comment: Unlke with JavaScript, There should be nothing special required for Python if type hints are written in your editor or used from an installed package. You do not need a special docstring to make it work.

Comment: That docstring is for the benefit of documentation generators like Sphinx, not static type checkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner and @Mikko i knew it had nothing to do with the doc string. So i checked all the other things and just realized i did the import wrong. I changed it and now it works:

```
from src.package_name.types import *
```

```
from .types import *
```